# Link dropdown lists in a sheet with database from 2 other sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dropdown

here's my problem. I've got 2 databases on different sheets. One is the 2020 sales of 4 employees and the other sheet is the 2021 sales of the same 4 employees. Each employees has 5 amount of sales in different columns that need to be displayed on a third sheet. The third sheet needs 2 dropdown lists, one choosing the employee and another one choosing the year of the sales for this employee. Then, the 5 amount of sales for the chosen employee and year are displayed in different columns. Can you help me with that ?

I'm obligated to use of the ADDRESS and INDIRECT functions to make it work.

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 1

[image: Sheet 2 (2020 Sales)]

Sheet 2 (2020 Sales)

[image: Sheet 4 (2021 Sales)]

Sheet 3 (2021 Sales)

I need to be able to choose the vendor and the year for the sales and it is suppose to display T1,T2,T3,T4 and the total sales for the chosen vendor and year

Sorry for my english

(EXCEL 2019)

Answer (score 1):

If `T1` in your Sheet1 is in cell `B10` and your year sheets are named `2020`, `2021`, in `B11` use:
`=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$E$8&"'!A1:E6"),MATCH($C$8,INDIRECT("'"&$E$8&"'!A1:A6"),0),MATCH(B$10,INDIRECT("'"&$E$8&"'!1:1"),0))`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you explained here, T1 in sheet 1 is in B10 and the other sheets are named 2020 and 2021 respectively. I need to be able to choose the vendor and the year in two dropdown lists on Sheet 1 and its supposed to show the sales of the chosen vendor and year. The data are taken in 2020 if you choose 2020 and same for 2021. Again sorry for my english

Comment: I changed my answer to the given info in your comment